# Кто из нас прав?

Tags: склонение

Здравствуйте!наш город называется Удачный,подписывая тетрадь своей дочери,я написала"...ученицы *"А" класса средней школы #* города Удачный"  учительница зачеркнула кавычки около буквы "А" и переправила "города Удачный" на "города Удачного" ...кто из нас прав?

Answer (score 3):

Название согласуется со словом город в падеже: города Удачного. Так что учительница права. А вот с кавычками - непринципиально. Без них, конечно, лучше, проще, но, если уж поставили, пусть стоят.

Comment: Да нет, кавычки тут тоже не по правилам. Это же город, не совхоз какой. Топонимы в кавычки не берутся. Так что учителка права во всем.

Comment: кавычки у названия класса, а не у города